# How to fit rotated hyperbola accurately?

Tags: curve-fitting, non-linear-regression, hyperbolic-function

My experimental data points looks like pieces of hyperbola. Below I provide a code (Matlab), which generates "dummy" data, which is very similar to original one:

```
function [x_out,y_out,alpha1,alpha2,ecK,offsetX,offsetY,branchDirection] = dummyGenerator(mu_alpha)
    alpha_range=0.1;
    numberPoint2Return=100; % number of points to return
    ecK=10.^((rand(1)-0.5)*2*2); % eccentricity-related parameter
    % slope of the first asimptote (radians)
    alpha1 = ((rand(1)-0.5)*alpha_range+mu_alpha); 
    % slope of the first asimptote (radians)
    alpha2 = -((rand(1)-0.5)*alpha_range+mu_alpha); 
    
    beta = pi-abs(alpha1-alpha2); % angle between asimptotes (radians)

    branchDirection = datasample([0,1],1); % where branch directed 
                                           % up: branchDirection==0; 
                                           % down: branchDirection==1;
    % generate branch
    x = logspace(-3,2,numberPoint2Return*100)'; %over sampling
    y = (tan(pi/2-beta)*x+ecK./x);
    % rotate branch using branchDirection
    theta = -(pi/2-alpha1)-pi*branchDirection;
    % get rotation matrix
    rotM = [ cos(theta),  -sin(theta);
             sin(theta),  cos(theta) ];
    % get rotated coordinates       
    XY1=[x,y]*rotM;
    x1=XY1(:,1); y1=XY1(:,2);
    % remove possible Inf
    x1(~isfinite(y1))=[];
    y1(~isfinite(y1))=[];
    % add noise
    y1=((rand(numel(y1),1)-0.5)+y1);
    % downsampling
    %x_out=linspace(min(x1),max(x1),numberPoint2Return)';
    x_out=linspace(-10,10,numberPoint2Return)';
    y_out=interp1(x1,y1,x_out,'nearest');

    % randomize offset
    offsetX=(rand(1)-0.5)*50;
    offsetY=(rand(1)-0.5)*50;
    x_out=x_out+offsetX;
    y_out=y_out+offsetY;

end
```

Typical results are presented on figure:

[image]

The data has following important property: slopes of both asymptotes comes from the same distribution (just different signs), so for my fitting I have rather goo estimation for `mu_alpha`.

Now starts the problematic part. I try to fit these data points. The main idea of my approach is to find a rotation to obtain `y=k*x+b/x` shape and then just fit it.

I use the following code:

```
function Rsquare = fitFunction(x,y,alpha1,alpha2,ecK,offsetX,offsetY)
    R=[];
    for branchDirection=[0 1]
    
        % translate back
    xt=x-offsetX;
    yt=y-offsetY;
    % rotate back
    theta = (pi/2-alpha1)+pi*branchDirection;
    rotM = [ cos(theta),  -sin(theta);
             sin(theta),  cos(theta) ];
    XY1=[xt,yt]*rotM;
    x1=XY1(:,1); y1=XY1(:,2);
    % get fitted values
    beta = pi-abs(alpha1-alpha2);
    %xf = logspace(-3,2,10^3)';
    y1=y1(x1>0);
    x1=x1(x1>0);
    %x1=x1-min(x1);
    xf=sort(x1);
    yf=(tan(pi/2-beta)*xf+ecK./xf);
    R(end+1)=sum((xf-x1).^2+(yf-y1).^2);
        
        
    end
Rsquare=min(R);
end
```

Unfortunately this code works not good, very often I have bad results, even when I use known(from simulation) initial parameters.

**Could You help me to find a good solution for such fitting problem?**

## UPDATE:

I find a solution (see Answer), but
**I still have a small problem - my estimation of `a`parameter is bad, sometimes I did no have good fits because of this reason.**

Could You suggest some ideas how to estimate a from experimental point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the main problem (it was my brain as usually)! I did not know about general equation of hyperbola. So equation for my hyperbolas are:

((x-x0)/a).^2-((y-y0)/b).^2=-1

So ,we may not take care about sign, then I may use the following code:

```
mu_alpha=pi/6;
[x,y,alpha1,alpha2,ecK,offsetX,offsetY,branchDirection] = dummyGenerator(mu_alpha);
% hyperb=@(alpha,a,x0,y0) tan(alpha)*a*sqrt(((x-x0)/a).^2+1)+y0;
hyperb=@(x,P) tan(P(1))*P(2)*sqrt(((x-P(3))./P(2)).^2+1)+P(4);
cost =@(P) fitFunction(x,y,P);

x0=mean(x);
y0=mean(y);
a=(max(x)-min(x))./20;
P0=[mu_alpha,a,x0,y0];

[P,fval] = fminsearch(cost,P0);

hold all
plot(x,y,'-o')
plot(x,hyperb(x,P))
function Rsquare = fitFunction(x,y,P)
  %x=sort(x);
  yf=tan(P(1))*P(2)*sqrt(((x-P(3))./P(2)).^2+1)+P(4);
  Rsquare=sum((yf-y).^2);
end
```

**P.S. LaTex tags did not work for me**

Comment: Looks nice - - have you compared the quality of your fit with some of the conic-fitting functions available at mathworks  "file exchange" ?